# Probability of random walk reaching one threshold before another using recurrence relation

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, random-walk, random

I am watching *Stochastic Processes I* by [MIT OpenCourseWare on YouTube](https://youtu.be/TuTmC8aOQJE?si=YfEQn5RqZY3gSDGY). A simple random walk is considered: we start from $0$, and at each timestamp, we take a unit step up or down the number line with $50$% probability.

We consider two thresholds: $B$ and $-A$ such that $A,B>0$:

[image]

We define $f(k)$ to be the probabilility of hitting threshold $B$ before hitting $A$, when starting from position $k$. **We would like to know, what is the probability of hitting $B$ before hitting $A$ when starting from $0$**. Hence we after $f(0)$.

When we are at position $k$, we either go up or down with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ (as always). If we go up, we hit $B$ before hitting $A$ with $f(k+1)$ probability. If we go down, we hit $B$ first with $f(k-1)$ probability. We have a recurrence relation:

$$f(k)=\frac{1}{2}f(k+1)+\frac{1}{2}f(k-1)$$

Furthermore, we also know that: $$f(B)=1$$ and $$f(A)=0$$

The lecturer [claims](https://youtu.be/TuTmC8aOQJE?si=TLTlwPMPInwLV6AE) that from these alone, we can arrive to the conclusion that

$$f(0)=\frac{A}{A+B}$$

**How can I arrive at this result?**

I am aware of the thread [Reaching a level before another for a random walk](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725996/reaching-a-level-before-another-for-a-random-walk), but I specifically would like to use the recurrence relation mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a system of equations

$$\begin{align}
f(-A) &= 0 \\
f(k) &= \frac{1}{2}f(k+1)+\frac{1}{2}f(k-1) \quad \forall k \in \{-A+1,\dots,B\} \\
f(B) &= 1
\end{align}$$

Which are $A+B+1$ linear equations for $A+B+1$ variables. These form a linear system of rank $A+B+1$, so their solution is unique. There are several ways to solve it. You can use a brute-force method and solve this matrix equation:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0  & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
& & & \ddots & & & \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
f(-A) \\ f(-A+1) \\ \vdots \\ f(-1) \\ f(0) \\ f(1) \\ \vdots \\ f(B-1) \\ f(B)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

However there is a smarter way. Notice that each equation says that $f(k)$ is the average of the two values besides it:

$$f(k) = \frac{f(k+1)+f(k-1)}{2}$$

There is a simple function where this holds, namely a **linear function**. And since the solution of the system of equations is unique, once we find a solution, that will be the only solution. And a linear function that goes through $(-A,0)$ and $(B,1)$ satisfies all our criterias:

[image: Linear function from (-A,0) to (B,1)]

Namely it clearly satisfies the first and last equations $f(-A)=0$ and $f(B)=1$ by construction, and it also satisfies the central $A+B-1$ equations, because the value of a linear function at $k$ is the average of its value at $k-1$ and $k+1$.

So we just need to find $f$, then calculate $f(0)$. Since $f$ is linear, its formula is:

$$f(x)=ax+b$$

We know that

$$ \begin{align}
\text{I. }f(-A)&=0 \\
\text{II. }f(B)&=1
\end{align}$$

Substituting

$$ \begin{align}
\text{I. }f(-A)&=-aA+b=0 \\
\text{II. }f(B)&=aB+b=1
\end{align}$$

Which we can solve for $a,b$:

$$\begin{align}
aA&\stackrel{\text{I.}}{=}b \\
aB+aA&\stackrel{\text{II.}}{=}1 \\
a(B+A)&=1 \\
a&=\frac{1}{A+B} \\
b&\stackrel{\text{I.}}{=}\frac{A}{A+B}
\end{align}$$

So

$$f(0)=0a+b=b=\frac{A}{A+B} \quad \square$$

Answer (score 0):

You have the recurrence relation:

$$
f(k)=\frac{1}{2}\left[f(k+1)+f(k-1)\right]
$$

Perform some algebra manipulations to obtain:

$$
f(k)-f(k-1)=f(k+1)-f(k)
$$

Do you see something linear here?

Comment: Sorry, not yet... Perhaps you could expand the argument a bit more?

Comment: @zabop the function increases at a constant rate, when you plot it you get a straight line

Comment: Nice. Once we recognize that, we can you the procedure in [Daniel P's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4830372/590567), right?

Comment: @zabop a little over the top. You simply needs to find a line equation that satisfies $f(-A)=m\cdot(-A)+n=0$ and $f(B)=m\cdot B+n=1$. Once you find $m$ and $n$, you can compute $f(0)$ or the value at any point